# ngCordova social sharing - Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed [social sharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#4a-usage-on-ios-and-android) and followed the instructions, with installing ngCordova, and setting up config.xml file, but when I tried my Ionic app in the chrome browser I got he error:

> Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

My files are setup like this:

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', ...other dependencies])
```

Function in my controller:

```
$scope.share = function() {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.share("This is your message", "This is your subject", null, $location.absUrl());
  }
```

I have added the links for scripts in my index.html:

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The icon for sharing in the view:

```
<img ng-click="share()" class="social-images" src="icons/facebook.svg"/>
```

Part of my config.xml:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
```

Also when I have config.xml like that, I get a parse error, and when I leave the `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />` out it works fine on the usb pluged in device.

Comment: this plugin will not work in browser, configure properly and try after build or on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

1- The plugin is added to your project by running the following from CLI:

> cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

2- The plugin is listed in the controller parameters:

> app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, ..., 
>   **$cordovaSocialSharing**){
>       ....
>       }

3- You are testing the plugin in **device** or **emulator**, most Cordova plugins are not available in browser.

Comment: yes, I did all that, and it is working in  devices and emulators, as you said it is just not working in browsers. Only thing left is I can't use <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" /> in my config.xml as it gives me parse error.

Comment: Yes, most cordova plugins are not intended to be used in browsers, you must build your project for device or emulator in order to get them running.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it correctly and it should work. **It does not work in the browser**, though. So **you will need to use Ionic View or your app to being able to use and see it**. So yes: it won't be possible to make it work on Google Chrome and probably you'll get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined
```

This does not mean it doesn't work on your app, though. So upload it first and try it on your mobile phone.

This is what works for me:

**App.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.share = function() {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.share("This is your message", "This is your subject", null, $location.absUrl());
  }
```

**Index.html:**

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<img ng-click="share()" class="social-images" src="icons/facebook.svg"/>
```

Notice that I haven't added anything to config.xml. It works like this for me.